# Outlook Search folder -- How to filter messages that have one category but don't have another?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007, search-folder

I'm coming from a Google Apps setup at my old company to Outlook 2007 at my new company, and I'm trying to make it feel "more like home."

I plan to use Search Folders to handle my Status labels, but the kicker is that I also have a "Finished" category. So, if a message has the category "Next Action" but also has the Category "Finished", I would like it not to show up in the search folder.

Taking the Next Action category as an example, I set up a search folder with the following criteria:

- Category --> is exactly "S/Next Action"
- Category --> Doesn't Contain "Finished"

However, this filter seems to be an "or" filter, not an "and" filter. So, I am getting all messages with Next Action, but also all messages that don't have the "finished" category.

What's the best way to remedy this situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some time, it appears I've found a solution for my specific situation for now.

### The Simple Solution

Query wise, I know I can perform this search using:

> category:("S/Next Action" NOT "S/Finished")

But in my case, the solution was a little bit simpler:

- Create a new Search Folder
- Under Criteria, in the "More Choices" tab, select "S/Next Action" from the categories list
- In the "Advanced" tab, Select "Categories" for the field
- Set the criteria to "Doesn't Contain"
- Set the value to "S/Finished"

This solution works, but of course it would run into difficulty should the query ever need to grow more complex.

### The More Powerful Solution

Thanks to [this awesome article](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/outlook-create-powerful-search-folders-with-query-builder/), I was able to figure it out. Below are the steps from the article:

#### Enabling QueryBuilder in Outlook 2007 via a Registry Hack

> - Run regedit in your run command or via <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
> - Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Ofﬁce\
>
>   - If you have Outlook 2007 navigate to 12.0 folder
> - Right click on Outlook and Add a new key. Name it as QueryBuilder
> - Exit Registry editor.

#### Creating the Advanced Query

1. In Outlook, select the "Tools" menu --> "Instant Search" --> "Advanced Find"
2. Click the "Query Builder" tab (which did not exist before our registry hack)
3. Define the first criteria

   - Field: "Categories"
   - Condition: "contains"
   - Value: "S/Next Action"
4. Define the second criteria

   - Field: "Categories"
   - Condition: "Doesn't Contain"
   - Value: "S/Finished"
5. Select the logical group

   - From the "Logical Group" drop-down, select "AND". This is key to making sure that Outlook enforces all the criteria (which is not normally the case; hence this post)
6. Set the Scope to of the Search to the Desired Level

   - In the "Look for:" drop-down, select "Messages" (likely already selected)
   - Click "Browse"
   - Make sure all appropriate folders are selected (I chose the entire mailbox)
   - Check the "Search Subfolders" checkbox

#### Saving the Query as a Search Folder

- In the Advanced Find window, click "File"
- Click "Save as Search Folder" and name the Search Folder.

#### Success!

So, there we have it! Problem solved.

Comment: THIS IS SNEAKY! 
I tried with Query builder with "Category" contains "S/Next Action" and it didn't work. I tried with "Categories" contains "S/Next Action" and it DID work! Sneaky because if you use Outlook (Field -> All Document Fields -> Category) then it uses "Category" (doesn't work for me) instead of "Categories" (works).

Answer (score 2):

- Right click `Search Folders` and select `New Search Folder`
- Select `Create a custom Search Folder`
- Click `Criteria`
- On the `More Choices` tab, click `Categories` and select `S/Next Action`
- On the `Advanced` tab, select `Field` > `All Mail fields` > `Categories`
- Change `Condition:` to `doesn't contain` and enter `"S/Finished"` using quotation marks
- If there are multiple categories you want to be excluded, put each in quotation marks and separate with spaces, e.g.: `"Category A" "Category B"`