# How to filter Outlook 2007 categories with a single click?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

In contrast to Outlook 2010, I have not yet found a less tedious method to filter the view by categories than `Filters -> Others (or similar, I have the German version) -> Category -> select one or more -> OK`.

Of course I could create search folders, but due to the amount of categories that would waste too much space.

Is there any way to significantly reduce the amount of clicks or key presses to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight improvement:

CTRL+ALT+A followed by CTRL+ALT+W (no need to release CTRL+ALT in between) brings up the extended (W) search in all folders (A). From there, a *single* category to search for can be chosen in a dropdown menu.

Comment: For more combinations of categories, have a look at [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/346527/35237)