# Outlook 365 - how to search for emails with ANY category

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I have pretty many categories defined for my exchange mailbox.
I have search folder in my desktop outlook app which displays all categorized emails grouped by category.
Is that any way to achieve that in outlook 365 OWA?

1) displaying only categorized emails:
I have tested that something as below would work. Is that any more straightforward way?

category:CAT1 OR category:CAT2 OR .....

2) sorting by category - no clue at all

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You are asking how to sync your custom searches that are on your Outlook (desktop) to appear in Outlook for Web Access (OWA) as well?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/346295/outlook-search-folder-how-to-filter-messages-that-have-one-category-but-dont

Answer (score 1):

To search for any categorized e-mail, I am able to do so by searching for only the word `Kategorie`. This is because every category of mine (the predefined categories) contain that word in their name, and apparently OWA searches include the category names.

Comment: Great hack... I have quited my job in the meantime so I have no outlook mailbox to try that out. Really a pity :)

Answer (score 0):

I personally couldn't get this to work, but you apparently can save custom searches to Office 365, if you [turn off Cached Exchange Mode temporarily](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/693) and restart Outlook 2013:

[image]

[image]

Your custom searches should show up Outlook for Web Access (OWA) shortly thereafter.

[image]

Comment: It has not worked for me. From what I read (https://www.msoutlook.info/question/763), the Search Folders are no longer supported with Office 365 OWA. My real question is - how to live without them...